# Convert Git projects into a JAR library

Tags: java, android, git, jar, libraries

I need to make a JAR library from a Git project.

https://github.com/Kaljurand/speechutils.git

How do I do that? There's no make file included. I need to use its voice to text functionality. Not only for this it project, but for any project I may like to use. I'm currently using Eclipse with ADT.

How do I make that Git into a JAR library? So I can use it inside my project.

I'm not familiar with Gradle or Maven, so I didn't try any of those.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gradle to make a JAR file of this. It should be easy to google how to check out the project and build it using Gradle.

You will need to install Gradle and then run `gradle install` on your project.

See: https://gradle.org/getting-started-gradle/#toggle-id-1

Comment: im using eclipse with adt.can i use gradle on eclipse too?i know android studio uses gradle